# Как сделать часть функции отдельным потоком?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5, c++17

Возможно изобретаю велосипед, хочется узнать все ли корректно (возможно у моей реализации не все учтено), или можно лучше, проще?

Есть ф-ция `MainWindow::someSlot`, где определенную часть (`MainWindow::veryLongFunc`) необходимо делать отдельным потоком, чтобы интерфейс не зависал.

```
#mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    int otherFields() const;
    void setOtherFields(int otherFields);

public slots:
    void someSlot();
private:
    void veryLongFunc();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int _otherFields;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

## mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <future>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::someSlot() {
    /* some code */
    QFuture<void> t = QtConcurrent::run([this] { veryLongFunc(); });
    while(!t.isFinished()) {
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }
    /* some code */
}

void MainWindow::veryLongFunc() {
    /* very long func */
}

int MainWindow::otherFields() const
{
    return _otherFields;
}

void MainWindow::setOtherFields(int otherFields)
{
    _otherFields = otherFields;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

Comment: Не совсем вкурил зачем вам мьютекс, но тем не менее, в qt есть свой механизм для работы в таких ситуациях - QtConcurrent. Вот простейший механизм "опоточивания" функции https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run

Comment: @AlexanderChernin исправил вроде. На счет мьютекса понял что не нужен. А строчка `while (_flagThread)` насколько корректна?

Comment: мутекс нужен в процессах, в потоках достаточно одной переменной

Comment: кстати если не надо ждать, завершения потока, то можно переменную и while убрать, а в veryLongFunc сделать сигнал...

Comment: while это ожидание завершения? тогда уж что-то типа  QFuture<void> t =  QtConcurrent::run([this] { veryLongFunc(); });t.waitForFinished();

Comment: @eri а можно будет продолжить с того же места?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev используя `t.waitForFinished();`, интерфейс зависает. Так что стало хуже

Comment: @AlexanderChernin интересно, буду знать, но для этой задачи вроде не нужно

Comment: QFutureWatcher для того чтоб слот разбить на два

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо делать `while(!t.isFinished()) {}` - вы тормозите главный поток приложения (со всем его GUI) до тех пор, пока поток функции не выполнит свою работу.

Как я указал в комментарии, вам нужно воспользоваться классом QFutureWatcher, который просигнализирует нам об завершении выполнения функции в потоке.

Заведите объект класса `QFutureWatcher в MainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow : ... {
private:
    QFutureWatcher<void> _watcher;
}
```

В конструкторе MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow():... {
    connect(&_watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, [&](){
        qDebug() << "VeryLongFunction's job is done!";
    });
}
```

Далее:

```
void MainWindow::someSlot() {
    QFuture<void> t = QtConcurrent::run([this] { veryLongFunc(); });
    _watcher.setFuture(t);
}
```

Таким образом, вы избежите отсутствия отклика от GUI во время работы ОченьДлиннойФункции

Comment: защитить другие поля от изменений, пока выполняется долгая ф-ция нужно?

Comment: @KtoTo при параллельном доступе к ним на изменение - мьютексом, или атомарностью. Если только на чтение, то ничего делать не надо